# Proxy to mock ec2.describe_regions() (AWS)

Tags: python, unit-testing, amazon-web-services, proxy, boto3

I'm makeing a simple proxy with Flask to mock the call describe_regions() of AWS.

The Flask server has de following code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from flask import Flask
from flask import Response
from flask import stream_with_context
# from httpretty import HTTPretty, register_uri
import httpretty
import requests
from flask import request
import time


RESPONSE = u"""<DescribeRegionsResponse xmlns="http://ec2.amazonaws.com/doc/2015-10-01/">
   <requestId>59dbff89-35bd-4eac-99ed-be587EXAMPLE</requestId>
   <regionInfo>
      <item>
         <regionName>us-east-1</regionName>
         <regionEndpoint>ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com</regionEndpoint>
      </item>
      <item>
         <regionName>eu-west-1</regionName>
         <regionEndpoint>ec2.eu-west-1amazonaws.com</regionEndpoint>
      </item>
   </regionInfo>
</DescribeRegionsResponse>"""


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<path:url>', methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'PATCH', 'OPTIONS', 'CONNECT'])
def home(url):
    return Response(RESPONSE, mimetype='text/xml')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Then I has the following code to test it. I use Boto3 to call the API for AWS.

```
from boto3.session import Session
import os

credentials = {
    'aws_access_key_id': 'sadasdasda',
    'aws_secret_access_key': 'dasdasdasd'
}

os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"] = 'http://localhost:5000/'
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = 'http://localhost:5000/'

session_boto3 = Session(**credentials)
ec2 = session_boto3.client('ec2', 'eu-west-1', verify=False)
regions = ec2.describe_regions()
print regions
```

The problem is: the Flask server get the petition, but the Response doesn't like to Boto3 and I get the following traceback error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/pruebas_mock/prueba.py", line 82, in <module>
    regions = ec2.describe_regions()
  File "/mock_aws/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 228, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/mock_aws/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 475, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/mock_aws/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 117, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/mock_aws/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 146, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):
  File "/mock_aws/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 219, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception)
  File "/mock_aws/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 226, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/mock_aws/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 209, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/mock_aws/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "/mock_aws/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 250, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/mock_aws/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 273, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/mock_aws/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 313, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/mock_aws/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 222, in __call__
    return self._check_caught_exception(attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/mock_aws/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 355, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

How should I make the response with Flask?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, boto3 (and all of the other AWS SDK's) will connect to services using SSL.  Your proxy Flask server does not appear to be using SSL so you can either use SSL in your proxy or tell boto3 not to use SSL for your proxy server:

```
ec2 = session_boto3.client('ec2', 'eu-west-1', use_ssl=False, verify=False)
```

The `verify` parameter tells boto3 not to try to validate the SSL cert but it will still try to connect via SSL.  the `use_ssl=False` tells it to use plain HTTP to talk to your endpoint.